# Find SUM of ODD and EVEN digits in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have an assignment to find sum of even and odd digits of `123456789` by conditional jump. The sum of even digits will be stored in AX and sum of odd digits will be stored in BX register.

I will use two arrays to solve this problem.

`2,4,6,8`

`1,3,5,7,9`

The sum of first array will be save in AX and second array in BX in hexadecimal format.

The problem is that I am beginner of Assembly Language and have no idea of conditional jumps to solve this problem. Can anyone help me to solve this assignment in a simple way?

```
    [org 0x0100]
    jmp start
    message: db '123456789'            ; string to be printed
    length: dw 20                        ; length of string
    clrscr:         push es
    push ax
    push cx
    push di
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax                          ; point es to video base
    xor di, di                          ; point di to top left column
    mov ax, 0x0720                      ; space char in normal attribute
    mov cx, 2000                        ; number of screen locations
    cld                                 ; auto increment mode
    repstosw                            ; clear the whole screen

    pop di
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop es
    ret

    ; subroutine to print a string
    ; takes the x position, y position, attribute, address of string and
    ; its length as parameters

    printstr:         push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push es
    push ax
    push cx
    push si
    push di
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax                        ; point es to video base
    mov al, 80                        ; load al with columns per row
    mul byte [bp+10]                  ; multiply with y position
    add ax, [bp+12]                   ; add x position
    shl ax, 1                         ; turn into byte offset

    mov di,ax                         ; point di to required location
    mov si, [bp+6]                    ; point si to string
    mov cx, [bp+4]                    ; load length of string in cx
    mov ah, [bp+8]                    ; load attribute in ah
    cld                               ; auto increment mode

    nextchar: lodsb                   ; load next char in al
    stosw                             ; print char/attribute pair
    loopnextchar                      ; repeat for the whole string
    pop di
    pop si
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop es
    pop bp
    ret 10

    start: call clrscr                ; call the clrscr subroutine
    mov ax, 10
    push ax                           ; push x position
    mov ax, 15
    push ax                           ; push y position
    mov ax, 0x12                      ; blue on black attribute
    push ax                           ; push attribute
    mov ax, message
    push ax                           ; push address of message
    push word [length]                ; push message length
    callprintstr                      ; call the printstr subroutine
    mov ax, 0x4c00                    ; terminate program
    int 0x21
```

Comment: The answer is 20 and 25. Oh wait, you wanted us to just write some code for you? One of the main purposes of education is to teach you to self-teach. You do not learn anything by just being told an answer.

Comment: Yes! off course

Comment: In other words: show us what you have tried and what your problem is. Then it becomes a question suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: Actually, I spent a lot of time to understand this scenario but not succeed. I just want some idea to solve this problem.

Comment: Which part do you not know how to do?  Check to see if a number is odd?  Or do a conditional jump?

Comment: I want to find sum of even and odd numbers by conditional jump.

Comment: Yes, I believe you have said that already.  If you are waiting for someone to write it for you, you might have a long wait, as this isn't that kind of web site.  In the meantime, perhaps you could start by writing a loop to add *all* the numbers.  Do you know how to do that?  Seems like the place to start.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider the binary form of the numbers you will see a pattern: The rightmost bit is set (=1) at an odd number and not set (=0) at an even number. When you isolate that bit you can "conditionally" add the number to the one or the other sum.

There are mainly two ways to isolate the bit and to handle it:

1. Use `AND 1` or `TEST 1` to get the Zero flag. It is set if the number is even (result=0) and not set if it is odd (result=1). Use `JZ` or `JNZ` ("jump if zero" or "jump if not zero") to handle the number.
2. Shift the number right into the Carry flag and use `JC` or `JNC` ("jump if carry set" or "jump if carry not set") to jump to the appropriate routine.

Please note that `AND` and `SHR` change the register. I recommend to copy it into an other register and restore it after the operation. `TEST` doesn't change the register.

An example with `TEST`:

```
...
mov cx, 9               ; Count downward from 9 to 1
xor ax, ax              ; sum of even numbers
xor bx, bx              ; sum of odd numbers

l1:                     ; Entry point for the loop
test cx, 1              ; Is CX even?
jz l2                   ; Yes -> jump to the label l2
add bx, cx
jmp l3                  ; Skip the following instruction for even numbers
l2:
add ax, cx
l3:
loop l1                 ; Decrement CX, repeat until CX becomes 0
...
```